# Python/Pandas: writing multiple Dataframes to Excel sheets using a "for-loop"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I cant imagine this question wasnt asked before but im not able to find the answere here: 
I got a Excel-File as Dataframe and used Dataframe.groupby on it. Now I want to save every single group into ONE new Excel file using a DIFFERENT Sheet for every Group. All I was able to do is creating a lot new files with one group in every file. My new "solution" does nothing.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)
neurons = df.groupby("Tags")

#writing Keys into a list
tags = neurons.groups.keys()
tags = list(tags)


for keyInTags in tags:
     cells = group.get_group(keyInTags)
     cells.to_excel("final.xlsx", sheet_name=keyInTags)
```

I get no errors but also not new file or writing to an existing file.

Comment: Hello! Maybe it would help to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207319/write-multiple-text-files-to-one-excel-workbook-on-different-sheets. I believe you need to open a file before the for loop and write on each sheet at every iteration.

Comment: If you get nothing, then `tags` is probably empty.

Comment: But if I go for print(cells) I get exactly what I want: all the neurons grouped by their tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I believe this is a better solution. Replace your for loop with this code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file_name.xlsx')

for keyInTags in tags:
     cells = group.get_group(keyInTags)
     cells.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=keyInTags)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Yes, thats excalty doing what i wanted :) Thanks a lot. Im new to coding at all and "better solutions" always help me to learn writing proper code.

Comment: You are welcome. I am new too, I just try to contribute to the SO community when I can, because it has helped me so much. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner solution for anyone still looking:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    for name, group in df.groupby("column_name"):
        group.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=name[:31])
```