# How can I Create a ForLoop with Pandas without deleting previous loop's data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the for loop below utilising a dictionary:

```
for position, url in dict.items():
    dfs = pd.read_html(url)
    df = dfs[0]
    df2 = df[['Summary', 'Next dividend']]
    print(position)
    print(df2)
    df2.to_excel(today_source_file, sheet_name=position)
```

The problem I'm facing is that each loop just wipes the previous data and starts again, so I'm only left with the data from the 'final' loop.

I have a total of 14 items in my dict, so I wish to end the script with 14 individual tabs.

Comment: imo pretty close to a duplicate. please see answer herefor writing to multiple sheets within same workbook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476803/42346

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your code with `ExcelWriter`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(today_source_file) as writer:
    # your loop here
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=position)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked!