# Consolidating files into one Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am decently new to python and I imagine this is a simple task. I have a bunch of text files of test data that I want to consolidate into one Excel file with different sheets for each file. All I have been able to accomplish is to make individual Excel files of each text file. I have tried a lot of ways to combine them but nothing has worked. The most I have managed is to make an Excel file with different sheets but the data does not transfer.
Any help is much appreciated.

Below is a sample of text files I am reading (/t = tab, /n = new line, not in actual text file):

Name of Tester: /t  name
 Date of Test:  /t 14/18/1900
 Time of Test Start: /t  00:00:00 PM
 Time of Test End: /t    00:00:00 PM
 Voltage (V) /t      Rotary Position (Deg) /t    Force (N)

-0.031 /t    0.000  /t -0.030 /n
-0.028 /t    0.000  /t -0.027 /n

Below is the the full code with the ClickProcessButton(self) portion updated. I do realize many of the imports are useless for this script.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import Series
import xlwt
import xlrd
import os
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl as xl
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import yaml
import sys
import os
import string
import datetime
import time
import openpyxl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from select_files import select_files
from parse_data import parse_datafile
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk



class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        # widget can take all window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # create button, link it to clickExitButton()
        exitButton = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.clickExitButton)
        exitButton.place(x=100, y=90)

        # create button, link it to clickProcessButton()
        processButton = Button(self, text="Process", command=self.clickProcessButton)
        processButton.place(x=100, y=10)

        # create button, link it to clickBrowseButton()
        browseButton = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.clickBrowseButton)
        browseButton.place(x=100, y=50)


    def clickExitButton(self):
        exit()

    def clickBrowseButton(self):
        global dataFiles
        global rootdir

        rootdir = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select Test Folder', initialdir=os.getcwd())



        #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#- Makes the folders if they do not exist -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
        try:
            os.mkdir(rootdir + "/Data")
            os.mkdir(rootdir + "/Plots")

        except FileExistsError:
            pass

    #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#- Processing the text files from Labview -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#

    def clickProcessButton(self):

        col_names = ["", " ", "  "]

        #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#- Steps through each file in the directory -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            workbook = xlwt.Workbook()  # moved outside the loop

            for file in files:
                # using try and except to bypass xlsx files. if other file types are present other than .txt and .xlxs,
                # the script will not run
                try:
                    workFile = (os.path.join(subdir, file))
                    with open(workFile, 'r') as f:
                        fileName = file[18:]
                        fileName = fileName[:-4]

                        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('%s' % fileName)   #workbook.add_worksheet instead?
                        for row, line in enumerate(f):
                            line = line.rstrip()
                            for col, value in enumerate(line.split("\\t\\t")):
                                if is_number(value):
                                    worksheet.write(row, col, float(value), style=style)
                                else:
                                    worksheet.write(row, col, value)
                # except:
                #     pass
                except:
                    "*.xlsx" in file
            workbook.save('all_files.xlsx')

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Tkinter button")
root.geometry("320x200")
root.mainloop()
```

This script is receiving the following error at the workbook.save('all_files.xlsx') line. The error is: IndexError : list index out of range

Comment: are the sheets the same for each file? same number of columns? same column names?

Comment: have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207319/write-multiple-text-files-to-one-excel-workbook-on-different-sheets

Comment: The sheet names are different in each file, number of columns are the same and the number of rows vary in length. I have the column names all the same.     Brajanna   I am trying out the solution in the link provided and will report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` and `ExcelWriter` to create your desired Excel output. I've assumed that your files are stored in a folder named `test`:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_files.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for f in os.listdir('test'):

    header_info = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('test', f), sep=r'\t', engine='python', header=None, nrows=4)
    header_info.to_excel(writer, f, index=False, header=False)

    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('test', f), sep=r'\t', engine='python', header=4)
    df.to_excel(writer, f, startrow=5, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response rahlf23! The script seems to be working for the header but not for the body of the text. I am receiving a ParseError: pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 46, saw 4. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.  Not sure what it could be reading differently in the file? I was using pandas before when I generated my single excel files for each text and was not receiving this. Searching around currently for solutions

Comment: Able to get the code to run finally. Not sure what is different exactly but it is processing the files now. Thanks again!

Comment: Absolutely, happy to help!